# Integrating Hono and Enmasse

Tags: amqp, eclipse-hono, eclipse-iot

I am trying to deploy hono with enmasse. For this, I already installed enmasse and created address spaces and addresses following this [repository](https://github.com/alexju88/hono-enmasse).

As described in [hono-doc](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/eclipse-iot/hono) on artifacthub. First I created a secret.

*my_secret.yaml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
stringData:
  amqp-credentials.properties: |
    username: hono
    password: HONO
```

and applied it into the hono-namespace:

> kubectl apply -f ./hono/my_secret.yaml -n hono

After that, I created my own values.yaml file to overwrite the hono default values,
as described in ["Integrating with an existing AMQP Messaging Network"](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/eclipse-iot/hono).

*my_values.yaml*

```
amqpMessagingNetworkExample:
  enabled: false

adapters:
  extraSecretMounts:
  - amqpNetwork:
      secretName: "mysecret"
      mountPath: "/etc/custom"

  amqpMessagingNetworkSpec:
    host: messaging-5355a0a.enmasse-infra
    port: 5672
    credentialsPath: /etc/custom/amqp-credentials.properties

  commandAndControlSpec:
    host: messaging-5355a0a.enmasse-infra
    port: 5672
    credentialsPath: /etc/custom/amqp-credentials.properties

  amqp:
    enabled: false

deviceRegistryExample:
  enabled: true
  type: mongodb
  addExampleData: false

mongodb:
  createInstance: true

grafana:
  enabled: false

prometheus:
  createInstance: false
```

At least I installed hono with:

> helm install -n hono -f ./hono/my_values.yaml c2e eclipse-iot/hono

But unfortunately, I get errors and pods do not run well, In particular I get these errors from all pods, that try to connect to the enmasse-Amqp network:

1. **Mount-Error**: Secret file "amqp-credentials.properties" is not getting mounted:
   The pod's logfiles says "No such a file or directory":

> 10:47:45.645 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] WARN
> o.e.h.config.ClientConfigProperties - could not load client
> credentials for [messaging-5355a0a.enmasse-infra:5672, role: Command &
> Control] from file [/etc/custom/amqp-credentials.properties]
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/custom/amqp-credentials.properties
> (No such file or directory)

2. **Wrong AMQP connection**: For some reason, all pods try to connect to enmasse through "amqps" even though I am explicitly saying they should use "amqp" through port number and not providing crt-keys! Am I wrong?

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, that would be great if someone could provide an exemplary "Hono+Enmasse" integration repository.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify extra secret mounts at the `adapters` level. You need to specify the `extraSecretMounts` property for *each* adapter individually, e.g. for the HTTP and MQTT adapter:

```yaml
adapters:
  http:
    extraSecretMounts:
      amqpNetwork:
        secretName: "mysecret"
        mountPath: "/etc/custom"
  mqtt:
    extraSecretMounts:
      amqpNetwork:
        secretName: "mysecret"
        mountPath: "/etc/custom"
```

Also note that `extraSecretMounts` value is not an array but an object, i.e. there must not be a `-` character before the `amqpNetwork` property.